# Error 404 on Wordpress plugin $.get call with space in parameter

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-rest-api

I have the following code in a Wordpress plugin:

```
        var texttofind = "hello";

        $.get("/wp-json/myplugin/v1/search_options/" + encodeURIComponent(texttofind), function (data) {
            var results = data;

            if (results.length > 0) {
                console.log(results);
            } else {
                console.log("nothing");
            }
        });
```

All is working perfectly.

But, if text inside variable texttofind has a space like "hello 22", i got an 404 error. If no space in parameter, all is ok.

Any idea? Thanks in advance